# How Do I Add A Space To This Part Of JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to edit some JS code but I cannot seem to add a space without the graphs that use this code to produce them, stops working.

I want to add a space into this part of code inbetween "valueSuffix:" and "config.rain.units":

```
tooltip: {valueSuffix: config.rain.units+'/hr'}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: There *is* a blank already?

Comment: Javascript doesn't care about spaces there. You have another problem.

Comment: Please detail "stops working". Are you getting syntax errors? Anything else? What exactly happens? Also, what graphs, and how are they produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
tooltip: {valueSuffix: ' '+config.rain.units+'/hr'}
```